# puppet defined types and variables

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet and I am trying to write a module to manage .bashrc file of 10 users. The following code is ok to manage the file of 1 user. However, I am unable to change the code to manage files for 10 users. I tried using defined types and variable with no luck. Can sombody please suggest me the right way to do this.

```
        init.pp:
        class profile (
        $bashrc      = $profile::params::bashrc,
        $bashrc_host = $profile::params::bashrc_host,

        ) inherits profile::params {

      anchor { 'profile::begin': } ->
      class { '::profile::config': } ->
      anchor { 'profile::end': }
      }

     config.pp:

     class profile::config inherits profile {

     file { $bashrc:
     ensure => file,
     source  => "puppet:///$bashrc_host",
     }
     params.pp:

    class profile::params {

    $bashrc_host        = "modules/profile/$fqdn_user1_bashrc"

    }
    case $::osfamily {

    'RedHat': {
     $bashrc = '/home/user1/.bashrc'
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not at all a job for a class. As you noted yourself in your [most recent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505623/puppet-defined-types-and-variables#comment56757356_34506483), this calls for a `define` actually.

Please don't use verbs in the names of your defines. Instead of `defineuser`, just do

```
define profile::user($host_name) {
}
```

Off the top of my hat, I'm not aware of a good pattern to use module parameters in your defines. You *can* however use the following pattern:

```
class profile(
  $default_shell = $profile::params::default_shell,
  $default_prompt = $profile::params::default_prompt,
  $users = {}
) inherits profile::params {

  $defaults = { shell => $default_shell, prompt => $default_prompt }

  create_resources('profile::user', $users, $defaults)
}
```

What happens is

1. values are taken from params, or hiera, or the invoking manifest
2. these values are gathered in the `$defaults` array
3. for any resource in the `$users` hash that has no `shell` or `prompt`, this default is used

Comment: Frank, I am getting the following error. Not sure if it is something to do with the puppet version or ruby version I am using:
Could not retrieve package_provider: uninitialized constant Gem
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: could not create resource of unknown type profile::user at /etc/puppet/modules/profile/manifests/init.pp:12 on node

Comment: puppet version I am using is 2.7

Comment: The snippet assumes that you have a `define profile::user`, and that it accepts parameters `shell`, `prompt`, and whatever you pass in the `users` hash. I advise to read up on the `create_resources` function carefully before trying to use this code.

Comment: Frank, I tried to read about create_resource. However, it's going out of my head as I am new even to basics of puppet. Following is how I adjusted my code. Please let me know what are mistakes in the below code. My requirement is to put .bashrc file into the home dir of different users.
params.pp:
    define profile::user(username=$name) {
    
      case $::osfamily {

    'RedHat': {
      $bashrc          = '/home/$name/.bashrc'
    }

init.pp:

    $users            = ('user1')

    ) inherits profile::params {

    create_resources('profile::user', $users)

Comment: It's "Felix", actually. This is not a good forum to teach you on this subject, seeing as you're lacking a broader understanding. Please complete the [training course](https://puppetlabs.com/download-learning-vm) before asking for more specific help. My profile also links to a book, although that is not the most gentle introduction, more of a crash course.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim of this module is to learn puppet then:

Add a param user to your class profile::params

```
class profile::params {

$bashrc_host        = "modules/profile/$fqdn_user1_bashrc"
$user               = 'user1',

}
case $::osfamily {

'RedHat': {
 $bashrc = "/home/$user/.bashrc"
}

}
```

After this, you can use a combination of array or hiera and [ensure_resource](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#ensure_resource) This still is not the most elegant solution, but baby steps.

If your intend is to actually manage the bashrc for various users, I would recommend using a pre existing module such as [account](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/accounts#bashrc_content)

Comment: Thank You Prateek for the reply.I wrote the code which does the job using the same format which is there in module you asked to install. However considering puppet best practices to use params.pp and the existing environment the code should only be placed using params,config and init files. Hence I have a confusion how to use defined type or arrays in params file . Also, we donot have heira implemented already.

Comment: following code works. However it should be done using params.pp:  class profile {
        profile::defineuser { "user":
        host_name => "host1",

         }


        defineuser.pp

        define appuserprofile::defineuser (username = $name){


        file { "/home/${username}/.bashrc":
          ensure => file,
          source  => "puppet:///modules/profile/${fqdn}_${username}_bashrc",
        }
        }